# How to prevent jquery mobile from handling post request with ajax in django

Tags: jquery, python, django, mobile

I have trouble integrating jquery mobile for my django project. Especially the log-in functionality seems not to work out of the box with jquery mobile(JQM). JQM uses ajax for handling post requests, which i want to prevent. On this site http://blog.vrplumber.com/index.php?/archives/2511-Miscellaneous-jQuery-Mobile-+-Django-tips.html

i read that it is possible to prevent JQM from doing that by adding

> data-json="false"

but where do i add that? In the template or in the view? I tried different variations with no effect.

Here is my login view:

```
def login(request):        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['u']
        password = request.POST['p']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                msg.append("Hello %s your login was successful"% username)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                msg.append("disabled account")
        else:
            msg.append("invalid login")

    return render_to_response('login.html')
```

the template looks like the following...

```
    {% block content %}

        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            Login:&nbsp; <input type="text" name="u">
            <br/>
            Password:&nbsp; <input type="password" name="p">
            <input  type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    {% if errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="logout"> Logout </a>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay figured it out by myself:
just add this javascript snippet into your template head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    ajaxEnabled:false;    
    });
    </script>
```